# Is there any way to use @wordpress/i18n for <5.0?

Tags: translation

I'm looking to make use of translation strings inside my JS files and unfortunately, I've read that `@wordpress/i18n` doesn't work <5.0. Are there any tools/libraries that help me with this?

Comment: What's the reason for using pre-5.0? The only reason I can think of is that you're unaware of the classic editor plugin. The best practice solution to this is to upgrade to 5.0+

Comment: @TomJNowell I want to be able to use translations in my JS files. If you're aware of any alternatives, please do let me know.

Comment: If you can answer my question, it's important and unavoidable. You may consider it irrelevant, but humour us and demonstrate that. You shouldn't be using a WordPress version that old, if you can't update WordPress then you need to share why. Otherwise the answer is no, that library requires a newer version of WordPress

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't choose what version of WP clients use, unfortunately. As per our stats, ~9% of our customers are still running on 4.9. What are the alternatives to this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No. That library requires a newer version of WordPress.** If you want to use that library then you need to update your version of WordPress to a more recent version.

Answer (score 2):

Although the mentioned library brings an advanced localization abilities (the most important one is the availability of `_n` function), there is a legacy way of localizing used javascript files with the [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function available for many years since WordPress 2.2. Here is an example of localizing [Magnific Popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) script ([source](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/raw/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js)) from one of my sites. First, you should change all the hardcoded messages inside the script (here is the patch file for `jquery.magnific-popup.js` script to show how it can be done):

```
--- jquery.magnific-popup.js
+++ jquery.magnific-popup.js
@@ -895,9 +895,9 @@
 
        closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close">&#215;</button>',
 
-       tClose: 'Close (Esc)',
+       tClose: mfp_msg.close,
 
-       tLoading: 'Loading...',
+       tLoading: mfp_msg.loading,
 
        autoFocusLast: true
 
@@ -974,7 +974,7 @@
    options: {
        hiddenClass: 'hide', // will be appended with `mfp-` prefix
        markup: '',
-       tNotFound: 'Content not found'
+       tNotFound: mfp_msg.content_not_found
    },
    proto: {
 
@@ -1047,7 +1047,7 @@
    options: {
        settings: null,
        cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
-       tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.'
+       tError: mfp_msg.content_not_loaded
    },
 
    proto: {
@@ -1144,7 +1144,7 @@
        cursor: 'mfp-zoom-out-cur',
        titleSrc: 'title',
        verticalFit: true,
-       tError: '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.'
+       tError: mfp_msg.image_not_loaded
    },
 
    proto: {
@@ -1677,9 +1677,9 @@
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        arrows: true,
 
-       tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)',
-       tNext: 'Next (Right arrow key)',
-       tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
+       tPrev: mfp_msg.previous,
+       tNext: mfp_msg.next,
+       tCounter: mfp_msg.current
    },
 
    proto: {
```

Next, you use localized script the following way:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
$magnific_popup_messages = array(
    'close'              => __( 'Close (Esc)', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'loading'            => __( 'Loading...', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'content_not_found'  => __( 'Content not found', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'content_not_loaded' => __( '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'image_not_loaded'   => __( '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'previous'           => __( 'Previous (Left arrow key)', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'next'               => __( 'Next (Right arrow key)', 'your-text-domain' ),
    'current'            => __( '%curr% of %total%', 'your-text-domain' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'magnific-popup', 'mfp_msg', $magnific_popup_messages );
```

This function is also can be helpful when you need to pass some parameters to the enqueued javascript (although it wasn't designed for that purpose, that type of using it is very popular).

Comment: Thank you! Naturally, I always knew about `wp_localize_script`, but, help me out a bit on my thinking here: **why exactly is this package not backwards compatible?**. I'm just worried, people who will be using my theme/plugins will be forced into using a custom solution when, you know, there we have  `@wordpress/i18n`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DanielSimmons I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. If it is **what exactly prevents this package to be backward compatible** the short answer is *the absence of `wp_set_script_translations()` function in WP < 5.0, an old way of `wp_enqueue_script()` function behavior (it doesn't take into account `textdomain` and `translation_path` properties of the enqueued script object), the absence of those properties in `WP_Dependency` object prototype etc etc*